# Half note with flags?

Tags: notation

I was looking at Saint-Saens Bacchanale sheet music and saw 2 half notes in a measure combined with sixteenth note stems in a 2/4 time signature.

What is this and how would you play it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is notation of between-two-note-tremolo, so this would be played as 16th notes alternating between f and a for the duration of a half note.

This notation is pretty much exclusively a piano notation, for other instruments such a tremolo is usally notated with non attached beams like this:

[image]